# requiero crear una funcion que me ayude a calcular el cdt, la formula seria: valor de intereses: cantidad*porcentaje*tiempo

Tags: python

```
def CDT():
    `introducir el código aquí`print("Bienvenido",a)
    b=input("Ingrese su capital:")
    e=input("Ingrese el tiempo a invertir:")
    por=0.03
    c=type(b*e*por)
    print("Su interes a ganar es:",c)
a=input("Ingrese su usuario:")
d=CDT()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

En python3 [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) devuelve un string. Puedes comprobarlo con `type`, ya que veo que lo utilizas en tu código y no tiene ninguna función ahí.

```py
>>> prueba = input('Mensaje')
Mensaje respuesta
>>> type(prueba)
<class 'str'>
```

En tu código le estas asignando el tipo de dato de `b * e * por` a la variable `c`, lo cuál da un error porque estas multiplicando dos strings y un float.

El código correcto, modificando lo menor posible el tuyo, sería el siguiente:

```
def CDT():
    print("Bienvenido", a)
    b = float(input("Ingrese su capital:"))
    e = float(input("Ingrese el tiempo a invertir:"))
    por=0.03
    c = b * e * por
    print("Su interes a ganar es:", c)

a=input("Ingrese su usuario:")
d=CDT()
```

Como puedes ver, tanto a `b` como a `e` le he hecho un casting para convertirlo de string a float y así poder multiplicarlo por `por`.